# Unable to connect SQL Server Docker containers with ASP.Net core MVC application

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am running windows10 with docker desktop v20.10.7. I am learning docker and thereby created an ASP.Net core MVC app running on container, further for database a separate container is created using below command.

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Pa$$w0rd2021' 
           -e 'MSSQL_PID=Express' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

Currently I am not focusing on persisting the data.

**Problem:** when ASP.NET Core application is trying to establish a connection with database (in the container), say while seeding database on application startup the below exception is observed.

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

Below are the SQL error logs from container at the time of exception:

> Logon Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only. [CLIENT: 172.17.0.1]

Connection string used:

Attempt #1:

```
Server=localhost,1433;Database=PracticeMVC,User Id=SA;Password=Pa$$w0rd2021
```

Attempt #2:

```
Server=localhost,1433;Database=PracticeMVC,User Id=SA;Password=Pa$$w0rd2021;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

Attempt #3:

```
Server=localhost,1433;Database=PracticeMVC,User Id=SA;Password=Pa$$w0rd2021;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

Nothing worked...

Support/Feedback to resolve the problem is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the correct SQL instance?  Ie do you have a default instance of SQL Server running on the Windows server hosing the docker containers?

Comment: Yes, i am connecting to correct instance based on documentation available online. Additional info: I also tried using docker-compose way, however the result was same. I see the same sql log (on container) everytime application is trying to connect sqlserver.
Yes, default instance of Sql server is running. Windows10 is the Host operating system.

Comment: What happens if you try to connect with the container stopped?

Comment: Be careful with separator characters in connection strings: `Database=PracticeMVC,User Id=SA;` should be `Database=PracticeMVC;User Id=SA;`.